# django remaining elements truncated

Tags: django, list

I am new to django, I want to get the id that has the name field contains "John". Below snippet code runs very well but,

In view.py

```
 all_ids=Employee.objects.filter(name__contains = 'John').values('id')
    return HttpResponse(" All id= %d " %all_ids)
```

It returns :

```
  All id=[{'id': 1},{'id':2} , so on  '...(remaining elements truncated)...']
```

There is a limitation to display 20 the items. So, How can I get rid of this limitations and (remaining elements truncated) ? 
Is there a better way to get a field's all values in a query without truncated ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

one way to do override it would be

```
all_ids= list(Employee.objects.filter(name__contains = 'John').values('id'))
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it seems working. How can I get rid of 'id' tag from query result, cause it is like All id=[{'id': 1}

Comment: Use values_list(id, flat=True) instead of values

Comment: Thank again, how about this, if I want to get the id by one one instead whole bunch of ids, how can i do that ?

Comment: what do you mean? can you elaborate

Comment: @JohnSmith having the list of ids, simply loop over it to get them one by one